# In Android, How can I access Google Calendar's (online) events data from my own application using Java?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

So basically I'm making a Calendar Application for Android. I would like to know the procedure of simply retrieving all the events from Google Calendar(online) when a user enters their username and password to the android app. Is it possible for my application to get all the events from Google Calendar and possible store it in an ArrayList or some other structure? If so, then can you link/show me an example. I can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: include two external jar files in our application.. Those two files are available in deps folder of gdata

Answer (score 5):

I believe you might find [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/) really useful.